# Racket's subprocess not finding files

Tags: racket

I'm trying to run a Racket file from the console as part of a deployment. Part of this is compiling files with pandoc. I have a command that works when I call it directly from the console, but it doesn't work when I call it from within Racket.

Successful command:

```
pandoc example.md -H pandoc.css
```

This gives me a warning about how I'm supposed to include a title in an HTML file, but then it spits out some HTML to stdout.

The Racket code makes three calls, and it displays outputs to stdout and stderr for each call. It's a bit bulky, so the code will be at the bottom. Here I'll just put the calls it makes and the outputs.

```
> /bin/ls ./
> /usr/bin/pandoc example.md
> /usr/bin/pandoc example.md -H pandoc.css
```

stdout from first two:

```
example.md
pandoc.css
pandoc.rkt

<h1 id="first-section">First Section</h1>
<p>This is an example markdown file.</p>
```

stderr for third:

```
pandoc: example.md -H pandoc.css: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Any clue as to why it can find `example.md`, but it can't find `pandoc.css`?

Here's the full code for pandoc.rkt. This is my first time using ports in Racket, so if I'm doing something in a horrible way, feel free to let me know.

```
#lang racket

(define-values (ls out1 in1 err1)
  (subprocess #f #f #f "/bin/ls" "./"))
(subprocess-wait ls)
(define files (port->lines out1))
(define error (port->lines err1))
(display files) (display "\n")
(display error) (display "\n")

(close-input-port out1)
(close-output-port in1)
(close-input-port err1)

(define-values (pandoc out2 in2 err2)
  (subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/pandoc" "example.md"))
(subprocess-wait pandoc)
(define html (port->lines out2))
(set! error (port->lines err2))
(display html) (display "\n")
(display error) (display "\n")

(close-input-port out2)
(close-output-port in2)
(close-input-port err2)

(set!-values (pandoc out2 in2 err2)
  (subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/pandoc" "example.md -H pandoc.css"))
(subprocess-wait pandoc)
(set! html (port->lines out2))
(set! error (port->lines err2))
(display html) (display "\n")
(display error) (display "\n")

(close-input-port out2)
(close-output-port in2)
(close-input-port err2)
```

Comment: Also, I suspect there are more tags that could be added.  I'm not sure what they would be.  `Subprocess` seems too general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several arguments: `example.md`, `-H`, and `pandoc.css`. Therefore, you should separate them according to the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._subprocess%29%29).

That is, instead of:

```
(subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/pandoc" "example.md -H pandoc.css")
```

Use:

```
(subprocess #f #f #f "/usr/bin/pandoc" "example.md" "-H" "pandoc.css")
```

Note that this is also true for `subprocess` of several other languages (e.g., [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)).